# how to get BSSID of Hotspot

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot

I need to get bssid of my hotspot using android.

```
WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                Method[] methods = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
                for (Method m : methods) {
                    if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
                        WifiConfiguration config = null;

                        config = (WifiConfiguration) m.invoke(wifimanager);

                        String ssid = config.SSID;
                        String bssid = config.BSSID;
                        System.out.println(config);
                    }
                }
```

i tryed using above code. but it give bssid null value

Answer (score 0):

`Wifi.Configuration.BSSID` does not return the BSSID of the AP on your device but is used to further narrow down the network selection when connecting to a Wi-Fi in station mode.

If set, the device will only connect to a network with exactly that BSSID.

For details, see: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#BSSID